# About gatekeeper

Tags: digital-communications

"Gatekeeper" is a telecommunication term.

The following paragraphs are from a technical book.

My question is quite simple: is "Gatekeeper" a software or a hardware?

> H,323 is one of those ITU(*International Telecommunications Union*)
>   recommendations that specifies an overall architecture and
>   methodology, and that incorporates several other recommendations.
>
> An H.323 terminal is an endpoint that offers real-time communications
>   with other H.323 endpoints. Typically, a terminal is an end-user
>   communications device that supports at least one audio
>   coder/decoder(codec) and may optionally support other audio codecs
>   and/or video codecs.
>
> A gateway is an H.323 endpoint that provides translation services
>   between the H.323 network and another type of network, such as an
>   *Integrated Services Digital Network*(ISDN) or the regular phone network, which in ITU parlance is known as the General Switched
>   Telephone Network(GSTN).....
>
> A gatekeeper is an optional entity within an H.323 network. When
>   present, a gatekeeper controls a number of H.323 terminals, gateways,
>   and *multipoint controllers*(MCs). But control, we mean that the
>   gatekeeper authorizes network access from one or more endpoints and
>   may choose to permit or deny any given call from one or more endpoints
>   and may choose to permit or deny any given call from an endpoint
>   within its control. A gatekeeper may offer bandwidth control services,
>   which can help to ensure high quality of service(QoS) if used in
>   conjunction with bandwidth and/or resource management techniques. A
>   gatekeeper also offers address translation services, enabling the use
>   of aliases within the network.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with electronic design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gatekeeper has both hardware and software. To talk ISDN or POTS you need hardware. You also need Ethernet, I believe, on the H.323 side.

There is also software to handle signalling, e.g. to turn a phone number into a H.323 address.